# cockroachdb Daily backup from EKS cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, cockroachdb

I need to take daily backup for cockroachdb and push to S3 , its running under EKS cluster with statefulset,  So can anyone suggest the best method to do this please.

Thanks.

Comment: I have already tried with using
 kubectl exec -it cockroachdb-client-secure -- ./cockroach dump --certs-dir=/cockroach-certs --host=cockroachdb-public --database=test-DB > test-DB-2022jan-k8s.sql , but its exit with error 
"command terminated with exit code 1"
But I can restore DB using ./cockroach sql , with same kubectl command

Answer (score 2):

the best way is to use the CockroachDB for backup.

```
CREATE SCHEDULE schedule_label
  FOR BACKUP INTO 's3://test/backups/schedule_test?AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=x&AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=x'
    WITH revision_history
    RECURRING '@daily';
```

you can schedule the exact run time using the RECURRING parameter.

```
CREATE SCHEDULE schedule_database
  FOR BACKUP DATABASE movr INTO 's3://test/schedule-database?AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=x&AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=x'
    WITH revision_history
    RECURRING '1 0 * * *';
```

the documentation link is [this](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/create-schedule-for-backup.html)

Comment: Its need  enterprise license